# how to create a database using flask

Tags: database, flask

I am new to programming and trying to create a simple web server which will allow users to create a workout from a list of exercises. I want to create a database which will store the users workout in the database and then allow them to view their previous workouts. I dont know how best to create a database which will allow this to happen. any help appreciated.

I have created a webserver using flask and have a simple function which allows the user to change the body part they want to train. then the user is shown a list of exercises i have hard coded which they can select and then they are brought to a screen which shows them what they have selected. I have also initialised a database using sqlite3 and created a database using the following code: `

```
def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database')
```

It is my understanding that i will need to create tables such as 'Workout' but i am unsure how best to go about this. Is using sqlite3 the easiest way or would it be better to use Xampp and php?

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlite is definitely fine for small projects. After you have created your db file (eg. db.sqlite3, whatever.db) you have to create tables. There are two ways:

1. First is to use `sqlite3` client tool in your terminal and create tables manually:

```
$ sqlite3 your_db_file.sqlite3
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Workout (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

2. Second is to use python `sqlite3` module which allows you to use **SQL** in python. Sample code can look like this:

```py
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("file_name.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE movie(title, year, score)")
```

More info about module in [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).